# What is the best way to load all navigation properties and their children in EF 4.1

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to get a `List<EntityType>`, each item has about 15 navigation properties that I need to load, some of navigations properties have a navingation properties that I need to load  too, this is a sample code

```
class AA
{
  public EntityReference<B> Bobj
  {
     get;
     set;
  }
  public EntityCollection<C> CCollection
  {
     get;
     set;
  }
}
class B
{
  public EntityCollection<X> XCollection
  {
     get;
     set;
  }
}
class C
{
  public EntityReference<Y> YObj
  {
     get;
     set;
  }
}

List<AA> AList = Dbcontext.AAs.Where(a => a.ID==4).ToList();
```

I want each item in `List<AA>` has been loaded with its `BObj` with its `XCollection` and and all `CCollection` items with its `YObj` of each.

I tried to load them using `Include` and `Load` but I think there is an **elegant** way to do that

also I tried to set `LazyLoadingEnabled` to `false` but that does't load the full graph I don't know why?

so please I need the best way to load the full graph of my `EntityType`

I am using **Database first** approach `EF 4.1` and `C# 4.0`

Comment: Your related properties need to be marked `virtual`.

Comment: @Yuck its generated without `virtual`,I added it but nothing changed

Comment: @Yuck I still have to use `Load` method

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I read your question as using **code first**, not **database first**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a neat trick I've picked up:

```
List<AA> AList = Dbcontext.AAs.Where(a => a.ID==4)
    .Select(a => new {a, a.Bobj, a.CCollection})
    .ToList().Select(o => o.a).ToList();

Dbcontext.Bs.Where(b => b.A.ID==4)
    .Select(b => new {b, b.XCollection})
    .ToList();
Dbcontext.Cs.Where(c => c.A.ID==4)
    .Select(c => new {c, c.YObj})
    .ToList();
```

Entity Framework will figure out how these various objects are connected. You'll be making a manageable number of round-trips (3 in this case), and the SQL query results produced will have relatively little repeated data.

Comment: that means I will make an extra query to get any child of any properties. it is heavy work in my case but It seems an elegant enogh to use it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turning lazy-loading off would prevent them from loading. Turn lazy-loading on and mark all navigation properties as virtual, this will allow them to be overridden so that dynamic proxies can be created. This will allow lazy-loading to work properly. Explicit loading is also an option (and considered by many to be better coding practice).

Edit: Oh I thought it was code first as well, excuse me. Then, if it helps, since Include returns a query object, you can actually loop through a list of them and add them to themselves to build your query dynamically.